# Sufficient statistics and UMVUE for joint poisson, bernoulli

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, estimation

> Given a pair $(X,Y)$ of r.v.s such that: $$X \sim
>  \text{Poisson}(\lambda)\quad \text{and}\quad Y \sim
>  B(\frac{\lambda}{1+\lambda})$$ with $X,Y$ independent, determine a
>   one-dimensional sufficient statistic for $\lambda$ and the UMVUE
>   (uniformly minimum variance unbiased estimator) for $\lambda$.

**Attempt:**

$$P(X,Y\mid(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n, y_1,y_2,\dots y_n)) =  P(X\mid(x_1,x_2, \dots x_n))\times P(Y|(y_1,y_2, \dots y_n)) = \prod_{i=1}^n\frac{\lambda^{x_i}e^{-\lambda}}{x_i!} \times \frac{\lambda^{y_i}}{1+\lambda} = \frac{\lambda^{\sum (x_i+y_i)} e^{-n\lambda}}{(1+\lambda)^n \prod x_i!}
$$

Using the factorisation theorem,
$\sum(x_i+y_i)$ is a sufficient statistic. It is however not an unbiased estimator of $\lambda$ because:

$$E\left(\sum(x_i+y_i)\right) = n\left(\lambda + \frac{\lambda}{1+\lambda}\right)$$

A trivial unbiased estimator would be $\frac{\sum x_i}{n}$, but then it is not sufficient.

To utilise Rao-Blackwell Theorem, $\sum x_i$ should be conditioned on $\sum x_i + y_i$. I am not able to proceed further.

Comment: I will look at this and possibly post an answer.  I find this way of over-working the letter $P$ irritating.  What is $P(3)$?  If one refers to $P_X(3)$ or $P_Y(3)$, I understand it, but if you write $P(X)$ and I consider the case in which $X=3$, I'm left with $P(3)$. with nothing to distinguish it from what I get if I consider the case $Y=3$ in the expression $P(3)$.  And one should distinguish between $X$ and $x$ so that one can understand things like $\Pr(X=x)$, etc. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I edited it to be more precise for what P(X,Y) is.

Comment: You will need $\displaystyle\Pr\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = x \mid \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i+Y_i)=w \right)$. This is $\displaystyle \frac{ \Pr\left( \sum_{i=1}^n X_i =x \right)\Pr\left(\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i = w-x \right) }{\Pr\left( \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i+Y_i) = w \right)}.$  Evaluating the numerator should be routine.  The denominator may take some thought. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Yes, exactly. $\sum X_i \sim Poisson(n\lambda)$ and $\sum Y_i \sim Binom(n, \frac{\lambda}{1+\lambda})$. I can't find a closed form for the PDF of the sum of these two

Comment: @MichaelHardy Does my last comment make sense?